# Detecting file modification with install4j

Tags: installation, install4j

We ship a config file as a part of our installation that we create via install4j. Suppose the user is doing an upgrade installation when we ship a new version of the product. Is there any way to determine if the user has manually modified the file after last installation ??

We need to detect if the user has modified this file, and then merge the changes that the user has done with the new changes that we are introducing by the update.

Any pointers / ideas would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

As of 5.1.11, install4j does not support this kind of content-based modification detection. Modification detection only takes file modification times into account.

Comment: Hi Ingo, Can you please tell me how to detect if the user has modified the file ? I can look for the last modified time of the file. However, I need to compare this with the time the last installation was done by the user. Any pointer as to how I would achieve that ?

Comment: Unfortunately the file modification times of the previous installation are not accessible through the API. Since you need to merge the content anyways, why not just always merge it? The merge logic will probably quite involved in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Windows installer compares a file's create and modify dates. If they are different the file has changed.

I believe you can solve this in a better way by writing the config file using the main application executable using "internal defaults" in your application instead of a base config file delivered via your setup. You can then re-apply all internal defaults to the existing file, add any new updates whilst keeping user changes where possible (sometimes you want to override what has been changed?).

The more intelligent an application is in its configuration and maintenance of settings, the less deployment problems you will see.